# Visual Studio Release build short-circuit bug

Tags: c#, release, short-circuiting

Debug build works fine, Release build throws a `NullReferenceException` for the following code:

```
MetadataObjectCollection<ExplorerAddress> storedExplorerAddressesCollection = null;
bool test = this.storedExplorerAddressesCollectionReference == null;

if ((test) || !this.storedExplorerAddressesCollectionReference.TryGetTarget(out storedExplorerAddressesCollection))
```

Is there some new broken optimization for release builds or something? This is pretty bad so I can't imagine its a bug with visual studio but I also can't see how anything I did could have made this break.

```
    at BlockExplorer.Services.CollectionsService.get_StoredExplorerAddresses() in C:\Users\Talos\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlockExplorer\BlockExplorer\Services\CollectionsService.cs:line 38
   at BlockExplorer.ViewModels.MainPageViewModel..ctor() in C:\Users\Talos\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlockExplorer\BlockExplorer\ViewModels\MainPageViewModel.cs:line 91
   at BlockExplorer.Pages.MainPage.ContentFrame_Loaded(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in C:\Users\Talos\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlockExplorer\BlockExplorer\Pages\MainPage.xaml.cs:line 75
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.BroadcastEventHelper.BroadcastEvent(DependencyObject root, RoutedEvent routedEvent)
   at System.Windows.BroadcastEventHelper.BroadcastLoadedEvent(Object root)
   at MS.Internal.LoadedOrUnloadedOperation.DoWork()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireLoadedPendingCallbacks()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at BlockExplorer.App.Main() in C:\Users\Talos\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlockExplorer\BlockExplorer\obj\x64\Release\App.g.cs:line 0
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: A short-circuit bug is highly unlikely. If you're sure the exception is coming from that if statement line, then my guess is `test` is `false` and there's something about your TryGetTarget that's throwing internally. I'd be interested in seeing your whole stack trace.

Comment: Agreed, I cannot imagine this is a bug with VS. However, WeakReference.TryGetTarget shouldn't have any problems either. Plus, when I break on that exception, the value of this.storedExplorerAddressesCollectionReference is null.

Comment: Is threading involved?